# Several entries for IPtables in top command

Tags: debian, iptables

Some functions of my website are running very slow at the moment with no obvious reason.

The only unsual thing is that after running top i got several entries for /usr/sbin/iptab

```
 3417 mysql     20   0 6069m 4.7g 4776 S  54.2 15.0   4093:30 mysqld
10797 www-data  20   0 98156 6820 2244 R  37.9  0.0   4825:00 /usr/sbin/iptab
 2719 www-data  20   0 97328 4416 2208 R  35.9  0.0   3238:22 /usr/sbin/iptab
27105 www-data  20   0 98000 4616 1272 R  35.5  0.0   6514:21 /usr/sbin/iptab
12786 www-data  20   0 97012 6744 2244 R  34.6  0.0   4803:52 /usr/sbin/iptab
27118 www-data  20   0 98000 4616 1272 R  34.6  0.0   6513:21 /usr/sbin/iptab
17002 www-data  20   0 96892 3088 1376 R  34.2  0.0   9738:37 /usr/sbin/iptab
18325 www-data  20   0 98720 4616 1276 R  34.2  0.0   8028:00 /usr/sbin/iptab
15829 www-data  20   0 96748  18m 2296 R  33.6  0.1  25:21.13 /usr/sbin/iptab
18329 www-data  20   0 98720 4624 1276 R  33.6  0.0   8028:44 /usr/sbin/iptab
 6587 www-data  20   0 97480  18m 2280 R  33.2  0.1 437:40.82 /usr/sbin/iptab
 9831 www-data  20   0 96148  16m 2364 R  33.2  0.1  29:30.66 /usr/sbin/iptab
 2723 www-data  20   0 97328 4408 2208 R  32.9  0.0   3239:13 /usr/sbin/iptab
15855 www-data  20   0 96748  18m 2296 R  32.9  0.1  25:00.36 /usr/sbin/iptab
20785 www-data  20   0 95896 2988 1280 R  32.9  0.0   9719:03 /usr/sbin/iptab
 5510 www-data  20   0 97696 6852 2244 R  32.6  0.0   4695:00 /usr/sbin/iptab
17043 www-data  20   0  373m  77m 5636 R  32.6  0.2   0:03.99 apache2
```

Running ps aux is one of the same...

```
ps aux | grep www-data
www-data   598  0.0  0.0  78720  9856 ?        S    Jul22   2:25 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data   800  0.0  0.0  78252 10260 ?        S    Jul25   0:25 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data   834  0.0  0.0  78720  9972 ?        S    Jul24   0:33 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data   876  0.0  0.0  78488  9156 ?        S    Jul20   3:47 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  1074  0.6  0.0  82212 13228 ?        S    Jul19  62:39 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1086  0.5  0.8 487156 266168 ?       S    Jul19  54:43 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1583  0.0  0.0  78720  9976 ?        S    Jul25   0:26 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  1608  0.1  0.0  68172  7116 ?        S    Jul16  16:02 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  1889  0.0  0.0  78240 10112 ?        S    Jul22   2:28 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  1912  0.0  0.0  68168  7812 ?        S    Jul21   3:09 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  2291  0.0  0.0  78240 10252 ?        S    Jul24   0:44 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  2547  0.0  0.0  78488  9204 ?        S    Jul20   3:32 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  2719 48.1  0.0  97328  4416 ?        R    Jul21 3243:26 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  2723 48.1  0.0  97328  4408 ?        R    Jul21 3244:24 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  3030  0.0  0.0  68180  7824 ?        S    Jul21   3:02 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  3103  0.0  0.0  68180  7820 ?        S    Jul21   3:00 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  3302  0.0  0.0  78488  9152 ?        S    Jul20   3:36 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  3449  0.0  0.0  78488  9180 ?        S    Jul20   4:29 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  3713  0.0  0.0  78488  9140 ?        S    Jul20   3:28 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  3793  0.0  0.0  78488  9164 ?        S    Jul21   2:58 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  3960  0.0  0.0  78488  9164 ?        S    Jul20   3:31 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  4117  0.1  0.0  68172  7120 ?        S    Jul15  30:33 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  4411  0.1  0.0  67844  6788 ?        S    Jul16  14:57 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  4455  0.1  0.0  68172  7120 ?        S    Jul16  14:38 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  4505  0.0  0.0  78240 10184 ?        S    Jul24   0:58 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  4561  0.0  0.0  78240  9816 ?        S    Jul25   0:02 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  4658  0.0  0.0  78488  9164 ?        S    Jul20   3:26 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  5011  0.0  0.0  78720  9112 ?        S    Jul25   0:02 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  5083  0.0  0.0  78240 10112 ?        S    Jul22   2:21 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  5168  0.0  0.0  78720  9964 ?        S    Jul24   0:57 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  5211  0.0  0.0  95432  6648 ?        S    Jul22   2:44 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  5223  0.0  0.0  95464  6432 ?        S    Jul22   2:45 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  5489 50.5  0.0  97700  6760 ?        R    Jul19 4702:21 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  5490  0.0  0.0  78376  8768 ?        S    Jul19   5:05 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  5510 50.5  0.0  97696  6852 ?        R    Jul19 4700:09 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  5585  0.0  0.0  78396 10228 ?        S    Jul24   0:55 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  5612  0.0  0.0  78376  8740 ?        S    Jul19   5:22 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  5957  0.0  0.0  78376  8712 ?        S    Jul19   4:54 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  6049  0.0  0.0  98904  6796 ?        S    Jul18   5:11 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  6109  0.0  0.0  78720 10008 ?        S    Jul24   0:58 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  6154  0.0  0.0  78236 10180 ?        S    Jul23   1:17 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  6413  0.0  0.0  78720  9812 ?        S    Jul22   2:12 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  6576  0.0  0.0  68172  7820 ?        S    Jul21   3:04 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  6587 44.4  0.0  97480 19372 ?        R    Jul25 442:44 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  6731  0.0  0.0  78376  8704 ?        S    Jul19   4:58 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  6805  0.0  0.0  78376  8704 ?        S    Jul18   6:56 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  6919  0.4  2.6 978604 864184 ?       S    00:12   0:15 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  6920  0.0  0.0  78720  9972 ?        S    Jul24   0:59 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  6981  0.0  0.0  99260 21308 ?        S    Jul23   1:48 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  7234  0.0  0.0  78720  9948 ?        S    Jul23   1:08 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  7373  0.0  0.0  78376  8724 ?        S    Jul19   5:19 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  7476  0.0  0.0  78376  8700 ?        S    Jul19   5:10 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  7571  0.0  0.0  68172  7780 ?        S    Jul21   2:35 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  7657  0.0  0.0  78396 10228 ?        S    Jul24   0:56 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  7832  0.1  0.0  68172  7120 ?        S    Jul16  14:56 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  7897  0.0  0.0  78376  8560 ?        S    Jul18   8:07 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  7989  0.1  0.0  67844  6788 ?        S    Jul16  14:08 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  8310  0.1  0.0  77972  6708 ?        S    Jul24   2:21 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  8328  0.0  0.0  78240 10252 ?        S    Jul24   0:39 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  8656  0.0  0.0  78240 10112 ?        S    Jul22   2:33 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  8669  0.2  0.0  68244  7116 ?        S    Jul14  31:54 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  9061  0.0  0.0  67916  7484 ?        S    Jul21   3:00 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  9069  0.0  0.0  78244  8560 ?        S    Jul17   8:46 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  9087  0.0  0.0  97372  2968 ?        S    Jul14   8:33 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  9209  0.0  0.0  78720  9972 ?        S    Jul24   0:55 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  9576  0.0  0.0  78396  8516 ?        S    Jul17  11:38 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  9579  0.0  0.0  78240 11116 ?        S    Jul24   0:37 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  9636  0.0  0.0  78488  9148 ?        S    Jul21   3:04 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  9648  0.0  0.0  78488  9148 ?        S    Jul20   4:24 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  9679  0.0  0.0  68288  7812 ?        S    Jul21   3:01 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  9681  0.0  0.0  67916  7484 ?        S    Jul21   3:05 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  9831 34.8  0.0  96148 17004 ?        R    Jul25  34:35 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  9898  0.0  0.0  78720  9816 ?        S    Jul22   2:19 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data  9918  0.0  0.0  78488  9148 ?        S    Jul20   3:46 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 10101  0.0  0.0  78248 10188 ?        S    Jul24   0:58 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 10469  0.0  0.0  78612  9264 ?        S    00:27   0:00 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 10620  0.0  0.0  77972  9764 ?        S    Jul22   1:58 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 10721  0.0  0.0  78488  9148 ?        S    Jul20   3:46 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 10797 50.7  0.0  98156  6820 ?        R    Jul19 4830:07 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 10803 50.7  0.0  97976  6796 ?        R    Jul19 4830:04 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 10853  0.0  0.0 140864  2948 ?        S    Jul16   6:12 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 10855 66.6  0.0 140864  3028 ?        R    Jul16 9603:52 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 11079  0.0  0.0  78376  8736 ?        S    Jul19   4:58 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 11203  0.0  0.0  78720 10072 ?        S    Jul23   1:05 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 11209  0.0  0.0  78720  9812 ?        S    Jul22   1:59 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 11550  0.0  0.0  78240 10252 ?        S    Jul24   0:46 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 12120  0.0  0.0  78240 10184 ?        S    Jul23   1:09 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 12786 50.7  0.0  97012  6744 ?        R    Jul19 4809:02 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 12809  0.2  0.0  68172  7128 ?        S    Jul14  35:12 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 12983  0.0  0.0  78376  8704 ?        S    Jul19   5:18 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 13047  0.0  0.0  78376  8708 ?        S    Jul19   5:27 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 13094  0.0  0.0  78720  9968 ?        S    Jul24   0:57 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 13236  0.6  0.0  81972 13036 ?        S    Jul19  62:14 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 13248  0.5  0.7 481732 259044 ?       S    Jul19  54:55 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 13340  0.0  0.0  78240 10112 ?        S    Jul22   2:22 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 14056  0.0  0.0  78720  9812 ?        S    Jul22   2:17 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 14196  0.0  0.0  78376  8568 ?        S    Jul18   8:30 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 14280  0.0  0.0  78604 10476 ?        S    Jul23   1:08 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 14647  0.0  0.0  78720  9972 ?        S    Jul24   0:51 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 14765  0.0  0.0  78720 10236 ?        S    Jul23   1:10 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 14848  0.0  0.0  68288  7820 ?        S    Jul21   2:45 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 14996  0.0  0.0  78240  8552 ?        S    Jul17   9:18 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 15650  0.0  0.0  77972  9864 ?        S    Jul24   0:49 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 15685  0.6  0.0  81972 13116 ?        S    Jul19  62:30 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15693  0.5  0.7 442892 235288 ?       S    Jul19  55:13 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 15798  0.0  0.0  78240 10184 ?        S    Jul24   0:56 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 15829 34.2  0.0  96748 18532 ?        R    Jul25  30:30 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 15841  0.0  0.0  96464  6628 ?        S    Jul19   4:39 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 15855 33.9  0.0  96748 18536 ?        R    Jul25  30:09 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 16015  0.2  0.0  68172  7116 ?        S    Jul14  35:33 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 16049  0.0  0.0  78488  9124 ?        S    Jul20   3:52 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 16060  0.0  0.0  96420  6652 ?        S    Jul19   4:40 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 16155  0.0  0.0  78376  8740 ?        S    Jul19   5:04 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 16584  0.1  0.0  68288  7156 ?        S    Jul15  16:21 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 16604  0.0  0.0  78376  8736 ?        S    Jul19   5:01 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 16973  0.0  0.0  78240  9792 ?        S    Jul25   0:02 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 16979  0.0  0.0  95932  4560 ?        S    Jul17   5:52 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 17002 66.8  0.0  96892  3088 ?        R    Jul15 9743:45 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 17239  0.0  0.0  78720  9948 ?        S    Jul23   1:09 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 17278  0.0  0.0  78488  9072 ?        S    Jul21   2:56 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 17562  0.0  0.0  78240 10256 ?        S    Jul24   0:47 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 17770  0.1  0.0  67844  3900 ?        S    Jul14  21:47 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 17791  0.2  0.0  68164  7112 ?        S    Jul14  36:58 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 17895  1.4  0.1 365720 63752 ?        S    01:01   0:04 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 17949  0.0  0.0  78376  8708 ?        S    Jul18   7:03 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 17985  0.0  0.0 397100  8116 ?        S    Jul21   1:20 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18010  1.7  0.2 394828 92584 ?        S    01:03   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18035  1.0  0.1 366044 64000 ?        S    01:04   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18053  0.0  0.0  68172  7816 ?        S    Jul21   3:08 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 18121  0.0  0.0  78488  9144 ?        S    Jul20   3:28 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 18229  0.9  0.1 350740 47868 ?        S    01:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18232  0.0  0.0  78392 10224 ?        S    Jul24   1:03 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 18256  0.0  0.0  78720  9972 ?        S    Jul25   0:18 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 18286  2.7  0.2 394708 92788 ?        S    01:05   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18287  0.5  0.1 350572 47272 ?        S    01:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18288  1.3  0.2 374644 71700 ?        S    01:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18294  1.1  0.1 350744 47080 ?        S    01:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18295  0.1  0.1 339932 37228 ?        S    01:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18296  3.5  0.2 380040 77732 ?        S    01:05   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18315  1.0  0.1 350616 47364 ?        S    01:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18320  0.8  0.1 350440 46428 ?        S    01:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18325 62.5  0.0  98720  4616 ?        R    Jul17 8033:15 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 18329 62.5  0.0  98720  4624 ?        R    Jul17 8033:57 /usr/sbin/iptables
root     18369  0.0  0.0   9244   880 pts/0    S+   01:06   0:00 grep www-data
www-data 18441  0.0  0.0  78720  8892 ?        S    Jul25   0:02 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 18606  0.0  0.0  78488  9132 ?        S    Jul21   3:10 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 18677  0.0  0.0  78720  9964 ?        S    Jul24   1:03 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 18679  0.0  0.0  80052 10468 ?        S    Jul25   0:00 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 18694  0.0  0.0  78392 10152 ?        S    Jul22   2:20 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 18715  0.0  0.0  78488  9172 ?        S    Jul20   3:24 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 18828  0.0  0.0  78240 10256 ?        S    Jul25   0:29 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 18832  0.0  0.0  78240 10256 ?        S    Jul24   0:33 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 18941  0.0  0.0  78248 11120 ?        S    Jul25   0:20 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 19219  0.0  0.0  78244 10260 ?        S    Jul25   0:19 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 19375  0.0  0.0  78376  8744 ?        S    Jul19   4:58 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 19545  0.2  0.0  68172  7112 ?        S    Jul14  34:48 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 19735  0.0  0.0  78244  8548 ?        S    Jul17   9:23 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 19876  0.0  0.0  97696  4444 ?        S    Jul17   5:49 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 19899  0.0  0.0  78376  8760 ?        S    Jul19   5:01 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 19989  0.0  0.0  78720  9972 ?        S    Jul25   0:28 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 20100  0.0  0.0  78720  9972 ?        S    Jul25   0:24 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 20105  0.0  0.0  78720  9816 ?        S    Jul22   2:14 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 20144  0.0  0.0  78720  9812 ?        S    Jul22   2:16 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 20247  0.0  0.0  97148  4360 ?        S    Jul17   5:54 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 20299  0.0  0.0  78720  9976 ?        S    Jul24   0:34 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 20665  0.0  0.0  68172  7788 ?        S    Jul21   2:44 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 20785 66.8  0.0  95896  2988 ?        R    Jul15 9724:13 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 20789  0.0  0.0  78720  9076 ?        S    Jul22   2:22 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 20863  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Jul21   0:00 [sh] <defunct>
www-data 20888  0.1  0.0  77972  5984 ?        S    Jul21   9:16 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 21145  0.0  0.0  78244  8548 ?        S    Jul17   9:52 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 21295  0.0  0.0  68284  7852 ?        S    Jul21   3:24 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 21423  0.0  0.0  68172  7824 ?        S    Jul21   2:58 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 21577  0.0  0.0  78488  9144 ?        S    Jul20   3:36 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 21616  0.0  0.0  68172  7780 ?        S    Jul21   2:35 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 21942  0.0  0.0  78376  8712 ?        S    Jul19   5:15 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 22021  0.0  0.0  78488  9148 ?        S    Jul20   3:28 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 22221  0.6  0.0  81988 13508 ?        S    Jul23  20:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 22229  0.5  0.3 176092 106236 ?       S    Jul23  18:21 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 22428  0.1  0.0  68172  7092 ?        S    Jul16  14:09 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 22467  0.0  0.0  78376  8712 ?        S    Jul19   5:14 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 22506  0.0  0.0  78488  9196 ?        S    Jul20   3:30 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 22566  0.0  0.0  78488  9148 ?        S    Jul21   3:05 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 22950  0.0  0.0  78376  8568 ?        S    Jul18   7:42 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 23147  0.0  0.0  78376  8564 ?        S    Jul18   8:35 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 23270  0.0  0.0  78376  8696 ?        S    Jul19   5:15 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 23565  0.0  0.0  98152  4656 ?        S    Jul18   4:59 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 23950  0.0  0.0  78240 10184 ?        S    Jul24   0:54 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 24008  0.0  0.0  68168  7812 ?        S    Jul21   3:17 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 24524  0.0  0.0  78376  8744 ?        S    Jul19   4:57 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 25028  0.1  0.0  68180  7120 ?        S    Jul15  31:33 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 25156  0.0  0.0  78248 10116 ?        S    Jul22   1:58 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 25229  0.6  0.0  81984 13060 ?        S    Jul19  62:36 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 25237  0.5  0.8 492076 271336 ?       S    Jul19  55:13 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 25266  0.0  0.0  78240 10208 ?        S    Jul24   0:55 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 25278  0.0  0.0  78240  9412 ?        S    Jul22   2:29 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 25381  0.0  0.0  78376  8704 ?        S    Jul19   5:20 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 25446  0.0  0.0  98528  2908 ?        S    Jul16   6:52 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 25452  0.0  0.0  78720  9824 ?        S    Jul22   2:16 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 25553  0.0  0.0  78240 10196 ?        S    Jul24   0:57 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 25737  0.0  0.0  78376  8708 ?        S    Jul19   5:20 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 25944  0.0  0.0  78720  9812 ?        S    Jul22   2:02 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 25959  0.0  0.0  78240 10112 ?        S    Jul22   2:20 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 26000  0.0  0.0  98036  2888 ?        S    Jul15   7:14 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 26116  0.0  0.0  78720  9964 ?        S    Jul24   0:56 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 26411  0.0  0.0  78376  8548 ?        S    Jul18   7:37 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 26533  0.1  0.0  68180  7124 ?        S    Jul16  13:43 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 26896  0.0  0.0  78488  9068 ?        S    Jul21   2:58 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 26966  0.0  0.0  78720  9948 ?        S    Jul23   1:17 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 27003  0.0  0.0  78376  8708 ?        S    Jul18   6:52 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 27093  0.0  0.0  78240 10256 ?        S    Jul24   0:47 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 27105 57.6  0.0  98000  4616 ?        R    Jul18 6519:35 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 27111  0.2  0.0  68292  7148 ?        S    Jul14  35:55 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 27118 57.5  0.0  98000  4616 ?        R    Jul18 6518:25 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 27616  0.0  0.0  78488  9148 ?        S    Jul20   3:47 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 27688  0.0  0.0  78488  9140 ?        S    Jul20   4:29 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 27700  0.0  0.0  78252 10188 ?        S    Jul23   1:13 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 27866  0.0  0.0  78244 11120 ?        S    Jul25   0:19 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 28026  0.1  0.0  78720  6776 ?        S    Jul16  16:18 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 28044  0.1  0.0  68172  7120 ?        S    Jul16  14:27 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 28223  0.0  0.0  78244  8548 ?        S    Jul17   8:59 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 28249  0.0  0.0  77972  9956 ?        S    Jul23   1:17 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 28561  0.0  0.0  78488  9152 ?        S    Jul20   3:47 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 29059  0.2  0.0  68256  7116 ?        S    Jul14  33:15 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 29360  0.0  0.0  78488  9168 ?        S    Jul20   3:34 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 29362  0.0  0.0  68216  7152 ?        S    Jul16  13:54 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 29477  0.0  0.0  97264  2984 ?        S    Jul14   8:41 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 29552  0.0  0.0  95220 17688 ?        S    Jul23   1:46 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 29617  0.0  0.0  78252 11120 ?        S    Jul25   0:23 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 29678  0.0  0.0  78376  8552 ?        S    Jul18   7:33 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 29815  0.0  0.0  78240 10184 ?        S    Jul24   0:57 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 29818  0.0  0.0  78376  8736 ?        S    Jul19   5:19 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 30219  0.1  0.0  68180  7124 ?        S    Jul16  14:11 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 30412  0.0  0.0  78720 10008 ?        S    Jul24   0:59 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 30608  0.1  0.0  68172  7112 ?        S    Jul16  14:32 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 30637  0.0  0.0  78488  9156 ?        S    Jul21   3:04 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 30829  0.0  0.0  96424 17324 ?        S    Jul24   0:56 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 30889  0.0  0.0 363300  7632 ?        S    Jul19   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 30891  0.6  0.0  82060 13604 ?        S    Jul23  20:19 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 30899  0.5  0.3 183244 113412 ?       S    Jul23  18:28 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 30916  0.0  0.0  78396  8544 ?        S    Jul17  11:26 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 31110  0.0  0.0  68288  7820 ?        S    Jul21   2:38 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 31139  0.0  0.0  78392 10152 ?        S    Jul22   2:14 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 31159  0.0  0.0  78720  9076 ?        S    Jul22   2:21 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 31226  0.0  0.0  78488  9160 ?        S    Jul21   3:06 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 31271  0.0  0.0  78240 10112 ?        S    Jul22   2:24 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 31404  0.0  0.0  68172  7992 ?        S    Jul21   3:00 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 31557  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    Jul19   0:00 [sh] <defunct>
www-data 31559  0.1  0.0  81632 10436 ?        S    Jul19  12:42 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 31692  0.0  0.0  78240 10256 ?        S    Jul25   0:23 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 31698  0.6  0.0  82088 13272 ?        S    Jul19  65:05 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 31706  0.6  0.7 471576 252764 ?       S    Jul19  56:45 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 31724  0.0  0.0  78488  9180 ?        S    Jul20   3:46 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 31889  0.0  0.0  78488  9076 ?        S    Jul21   2:57 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 32011  0.0  0.0  78244 11120 ?        S    Jul24   0:34 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 32068  0.0  0.0  78376  8748 ?        S    Jul19   4:54 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 32174  0.0  0.0  95340  2812 ?        S    Jul16   6:47 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 32204  0.0  0.0  78720  9972 ?        S    Jul25   0:22 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 32265  0.0  0.0  78488  9152 ?        S    Jul20   3:38 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 32537  0.0  0.0  78720  9856 ?        S    Jul22   2:16 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 32609  0.0  0.0  78376  8760 ?        S    Jul19   4:58 /usr/sbin/iptables
www-data 32635 34.1  0.0  96120 17772 ?        R    Jul25  24:19 /usr/sbin/iptables
```

Is this an indication that something is going wrong with my server?

Comment: Since it is by www-data (the web server) it is likely some administration or status pages getting information from iptables. Might be worthwhile to lock down these pages so they are not accessible to the public. Or it could be some automatic web server firewall scripts adjusting firewall rules based on traffic etc.

Comment: I am looking for a way to find out what these pages might be, but cant find of a method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't normal. IPTables requires root access; it typically wouldn't run at all as a non-root user (like www-data). And it definitely wouldn't run for days at a time.

But chances are that those process aren't actually IPTables at all. Your web server has probably been compromised, probably through a vulnerable script. Determining what has actually happened is a job for an expert, not this forum, but a few first steps should be:

- If possible, shut off your web server temporarily to prevent further exploits from occurring while you investigate.
- Take note of what those processes are doing (using `lsof`), then kill them all.
- Review all software running on your web site. Update any software that has updates available. Restrict access to anything noncritical which you wrote yourself, particularly anything that would have the potential to create files or run programs.
- Check for any PHP files in your web directories (especially any upload, cache, or temporary directories) which don't belong. Remove anything suspicious.